# How to use jquery code in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I put some jquery in my website that makes the text move to the right when the page changes. It works in Firefox and Safari but it doesn't work in Internet Explorer. My url to my website: http://katieduck.com/Courses/Improvisation%20Winter%20Course%20Dartington.html
Here is the code that is not working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tabvanilla > ul').tabs({ fx: { height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle' } });
    $('#featuredvid > ul').tabs();
});
```

Maybe you can find out what is wrong.

---

Hi Do you know which css problem I have exactly?
Where is the jquery easing I cannot find it on that page: http://katieduck.com/Courses/Improvisation%20Winter%20Course%20Dartington.html

Thank u,

ILaria

Comment: First step: Check what JavaScript errors Internet Explorer may be throwing. If code gets executed in other browsers, it's very likely there are some.

Comment: I found another error with firebug: jQuery.easing[this.options.easing || (jQuery.easing.swing ? "swing" : "linear")] is not a function - Maybe it has to do with this one?

Comment: Firebug is your friend with both Javascript and css weirdness.  You can use it to look at each element in your page, and it will indicate what css styles it is applying, and in what particular css definition each attribute was defined.

Answer (score 2):

You have a CSS problem, not a jQuery problem. jQuery is probably affecting the right CSS values, however IE does render CSS differently from other browsers, so that's probably the problem you are having.

besides, it's not showing up correctly in FF 3.6 anyways, so I'm guessing you have multiple problems at the moment